Websocket request is ignored in Spring gateway security
I have a problem with connecting spring WebSocket(Using sockJs).
Currently, we are using a gateway service(written in spring boot) to redirect incoming requests to appropriate micro-services. But I have encountered a serious problem.
Currently, our front-end developers are using Angular and they try to use sockJs. Everything is fine unless we enabled spring security in our gateway service.
Spring security contains a class called 'MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher'. This class is Used in spring's 'ServerHttpSecurity' class, where by default all requests with mediaType=*/* are ignored. The problem is that it seems in the websocket handshake, it sends a http request with this kind of mediaType, and thus, it will be ignored by gateway.
The only thing we need is oauth token to be put in the websocket handshake request (to be added by gateway token-Relay). So we have to enable security so that the gateway put the token in the request and send it to our desired micro-service.
How can I overcome this problem? I didn't find any solution to change the behavior of MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher or even ServerHttpSecurity to allow this kind of mediaType. (and even I don't want a global solution where it allow this kind of / for all requests!)
